# How to change CMAKE_C_COMPILER without losing configuration?

Tags: c++, c, cmake, build-system

When you change the `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` / `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER`.

CMake detects this and re-generates the cache, loosing any manually defined options.

I can see why the CMake project chose this behavior, In most cases it makes sense,

however it's not necessarily useful when...

- Using a wrapper (typically a shell script which calls the compiler).
- Using a prefix command such as `distcc` or `ccache`.

For example. I don't need `distcc` enabled all the time, and I would like to be able to enable it, only when I'm bisecting.

---

Is it possible to change the compiler command in CMake without re-generating the cache?

Comment: You can "transform" CMakeCache.txt into CMake script, which fills it. Then use this script with "-c" option when call `cmake`. That way cache will be reloaded using simple `SET()` instructions, without needs to re-check cache entries(which is much more time-consuming process). `CMakeCache.txt` -> script transformation can be easily implemented using, e.g., `perl`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, yep, writing some tool to handle this is OK, but if this is a common operation (using compiler wrappers isn't _that_ strange), then everyone maintaining their own Perl scripts seems overkill, especially since theres likely a way to stop CMake from detecting compiler changes.

Comment: Use a build-directory for each compiler. Then it is easy to switch.

Comment: @usr1234567, right - I do this already *(for different compilers)*, but in this case Im not changing the compiler - just how its activated, sometimes I have other systems running at want to use `distcc`, other times their turned off. Having to switch build dirs each time is inconvenient.